# What parsing the page means?

Tags: html, css

I came across following explanation:

1. If async="async": The script is executed asynchronously with the
   rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page
   continues the **parsing**)
2. If async is not present and defer="defer": The script is executed
   when the page has finished **parsing**
3. If neither async or defer is present: The script is fetched and
   executed immediately, before the browser continues **parsing** the
   page

does parsing simply mean loading the components of the page like texts or picture and layout and ....?

Answer (score 4):

Parsing means reading the HTML source. It is read line by line (tag by tag). Most browsers builds the DOM and renders the page (basic layout and text) while parsing the document. When the parser encounters a script tag, it pauses parsing (reading) the html until  the  script is finished (or continues immediately if async or defer is specified).
After the parsing is completed (the browser have read and interpreted all of the HTML page) it starts loading assets like images.

Comment: I have two questions .imagine there is no script for the sake of the question.1- when it reads the HTML tags does it translate them immediately to page components like text or it should read all the HTML first? 2- which process turns these reading into the  actual page that we see in the monitor?

Comment: The parser creates the DOM and starts rendering the page immediately. This can be observed on a very slow internet connection or a script that outputs the html very slowly. The page will still render partially even if the browser has not read the whole html document yet.

Comment: that's true .I saw in slow connection the effects .now it  seems to me that it reads codes as they have been written from top to button .for example I saw pages in slow connections with no layout or format and just some text and fonts . why is that?is it because the page first loads fonts and pics and then CSS layout? is there any order for reading the specific code first?

Comment: Usually CSS is loaded synchronously (non async) just like scripts, but I believe this behavior differs from browser to browser. It seems to me that most browsers parses the HTML and when it encounters CSS or images it starts loading them and immediately continues parsing the HTML. This means that it will try to render the page without css to begin with and later apply css when the stylesheet has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, is means converting the HTML source code into DOM nodes like elements and text.

Fetching of dependant resources will *also* continue, but that's in addition to the parsing.

Comment: What does fetching means?

Comment: @mohsendoraghi — Stackoverflow is not the appropriate place to ask for definitions of common English words.